# Animation moves armature

Tags: animation

I've spent a frustrating two hours trying to animate and running into the same problem.

When I move a specific object in object mode, the armature doesn't move.  When I put it into pose and move that object, the armature doesn't move.  When I record an animation and move that object, the armature moves all over the shop, messing up everything attached to it.

I've cleared parent (I think) between the object and the armature, and between the armature and the object.  (There should never have been a parent there).

Unless the problem is somewhere else, I think it might still be a parenting issue.  How can I see what the parent is - other than with the very-un-clear dotted parent lines (of which there are too many in the scene anyway)?

Thanks,

A

Comment: Look in the outline. If they're parented, objects appear "inside" the tree of their parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an object selected, go into the Object sub-panel of the Properties Editor. Under the Relations section is a Parent field where you can click an x to get rid of a parent or use the eyedropper to choose a parent.

Select the armature's root bone then go to the Constraints sub-panel to see if there is a constraint that could be causing the problem.

The Constraint sub-panel is (in blender 2.79) in the Properties Editor, 6th icon along. See picture:

[image]

Comment: Sorry...where is the Constraints sub panel?

Comment: Just answered your question by editing the answer - see the end bit.